# Installing on the Razer Blade laptop

Tags: system-installation, laptop

I was wondering if I can install elementary OS in a Razer Blade 2016. I have seen a lot of problems with the drivers with other distros, mainly with booting and the trackpad. I haven't tried to install elementary OS yet.

Comment: I couldn't install on my Razer Blade Stealth. http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9727/installation-on-flash-drive-produces-errors-did-i-install-correctly

Answer (score 1):

Linux supports i7 6th gen. processors from kernel 4.3, which does not come by default in freya. You can try to launch your system from Live USB to try, but you'll must compile a new kernel to get the best performance of your processor.

If you wan't able to launch the Live USB, try with *nomodeset* parameter from boot. That Nvidia 970m needs that you install 346 drivers.

More info: [Ubuntu and derivates on i7 6th gen](https://askubuntu.com/a/691245)