# Installation on flash drive produces errors. Did I install correctly?

Tags: system-installation, boot, usb-drive

I tried installing elementaryOS onto a flash drive on my Razer Blade Stealth with the unetbootin program.

I was able to get into the installation process although the screen was flashing on and off a lot. What I mean by this is that, the installation process was working (i.e. asking about keyboard layout, timezone, etc) but the screen was randomly going black in very fast flashes unless I moved the mouse cursor in which case it would look normal and not flash.
I figured this was just a glitch with the installer and continued with the installation.
I formatted the flash drive that I wanted to install the OS on with the Ext2 filesystem (was that a good choice?) and I decided not to partition a swap space because the flash drive is only 16GB and my computer has a decent amount of RAM.
The installation finished successfully.

Then, I restarted, got into the bootloader, booted elementaryOS, the elementaryOS logo splash screen displayed. Then, a loud static noise came from my speaker and the screen became a mess of multicolored pixelated rectangles and glitchy-ness.

I restarted and use the bootloader to boot into elementaryOS recovery mode where I received an error

```
UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
```

You can see the error message [here](https://goo.gl/photos/u6yDfMn93uNHfgX68). Sorry for the crap quality.

Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have the Razer Blade Stealth too and have the same issue with the garbled screen and crashing - [Elementary crashing on desktop login](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/elementary-crashing-on-desktop-login)

In my case I've installed it to the internal SSD so it isn't due to you using a flash drive as I have the same issue.

The reason you're having to run fsck is the filesystem was marked dirty due to the crash - if you use a journaled FS (like ext3/4) you probably won't get that error as it will repair itself from the journal after a crash. This won't fix the crashing though!

Comment: I looked at your post and your issue seems slightly different because you can get into the login screen which I can't do at all! Either way best of luck hopefully someone can help us.