# Elementary crashing on desktop login

Tags: desktop, crash

I recently bought aa Razer Blade Stealth laptop which I'm having issues with Elementary Loki on. This laptop uses the 7th gen Intel Kaby Lake chipset with an HD 620 graphics chip and a HIDPI touchscreen (12.5" 2560x1440 QHD).

I can boot to the installer without issue and proceed through the install (even the touchscreen works!). Once installed It boots to the login screen (lightdm) and I can move my mouse, type password etc without problem, but as soon as I login the machine crashes with a garbled screen.

While at the login screen I can alt-F1 to another console and login there without issue. while there I've checked a bunch of logs but they all end abruptly, I'm guess it crashes before it has a chance to log anything.

Things I've tried:

- explicitly setting an xorg.conf with tweaks from the Arch wiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/razer#Graphics_Drivers)
- Upgrading the kernel to 4.8 (as I heard it has many Kaby Lake fixes in it)
- Stopping lightdm and running startx from a console

Every time a crash as soon as the desktop starts to load.

I've installed Xubuntu 16.04 (as I had the ISO handy) and that works without issue - I can load the desktop fine (though the HIDPI support is a bit poor). From there I added two elementary repos, ppa:elementary-os/stable and ppa:elementary-os/os-patches and using apt installed elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop (as per this post - https://askubuntu.com/questions/766673/pantheon-on-ubuntu-16-04) but it still crashes as soon as I try and log in to Pantheon (XFCE still works fine).

I'm out of ideas - are there any commands I can pass to the kernel at boot, some sort of safe mode, or debugging? It's strange that lightdm works fine, XFCE works fine, but pantheon crashes hard.

Sorry for the essay - was trying to get as much info in as possible!

Cheers,
Andrew

EDIT: Added the fact it is a HIDPI display

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring this out? I had the same issue and now I'm trying to install any linux distro but it won't work.

Comment: Same. I am able to run Arch, Ubuntu, Windows perfectly fine on the stealth but have run into same issues as you describe. Please halp. Don't even know where to start debugging this issue.

Comment: No I never got it working - tried a few more things (mostly around different xorg configs) and have hunted through a bunch of logs but nothing gets logged when it crashes. After a few days tinkering I gave up and installed Ubuntu 16.10 with Gnome 3

Comment: I thing the Kaby Lake concerns are not the cause, at least I'm using a Dell XPS 13 9360 and it's working perfectly. I did upgrade the kernel, but it was running without the update. Wish I had gone through similar, to help, but afraid my KL chipset works fine.

Comment: Has there been any progress on a fix for this? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Any luck on this thus far? I just banged my head against the wall for about 15 hours on this problem and in these past 15 hours, I've gotten the damn OS to boot successfully three times past login. Couple of things I did in case people want to try and follow in my footsteps. If you're wondering what I'm doing now, I've quit and moved onto Ubuntu, which works without a hitch. If you find a solution, please do share. I installed every kernel from 4.9 -> 4.14 rc3, updated microcode, installed all drivers from 01.org, downloaded and installed all updates, changed permissions to proper ones for .Xa

Comment: Arven, I did system update and reinstalled grub and flashed my bios. Automatic login didn't work,I tried that.

Comment: I've got a question open for the exact same thing, which has had zero replies. Did you ever get anywhere?

Comment: @dannykay1710 I never got any further. Like you I tried the Juno Beta when it came out but it exhibits the same behavior - crashing as soon as the desktop starts to load. I haven't done any trouble shooting on it for over a year now, just tried Juno and when it was obvious the issue was still there moved on. It's a shame, I really want to use and support Elementary (I donated when downloading the ISO etc) but I don't know how to proceed from here

Comment: It seems like support is somewhat non-existent as well, which is a real shame...

Answer (score 1):

I've made progress, done updates and used clamtk to neutralise the trojan that caused it. I think it came from an ad-spamming website hdeuropics, where I watched a frebbie movie, I went searching for every possible file it could have got to but went too far and destroyed my profile's system shared user files, meaning I couldn't log in. 
I used terminal to find and obliterate all related trojan files, update system and cleaned it all up and it now logs in but then straight back out again on that profile. I can log into the admin profile and my son can log into his.
I could make a new profile and then maybe transfer the files to that. Unfortunately one of the folders has my registered user files for a game that I love so that's why I haven't made another profile, as you can't have 2 profiles with the same name. 
I was thinking to chown the files then move them and then move them again to a new profile and chown them back again, it could work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's "busybox" and that isn't present on my fresh install of Loki   try in terminal   _dpkg -L busybox_ before updating and adding packages to see if it's present